# How to set header & footer fixed at top and bottom?

Tags: vue.js

My footer can't fix at the bottom and I tried 2 ways. Each method is issues. How can I fixed them and don't affect my content component?

Using self-define "footer-bottom"(fix at bot, but overlap):
[pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rVWw.png)
[responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zbnb.png)

Using fixed-bottom(not overlap, but doesn't fix at bot):
[pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Ofm.png)
[responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azQKb.png)

## App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";

// Content
import ShowsSection from "./components/ShowsSection.vue";
</script>


<template>
  <Header class="header-top" />

  <!-- Content -->
  <ShowsSection />

  <!-- Use: fixed-bottom ?  -->
  <Footer class="footer-bottom" />
</template>


<style scoped>
.header-top {
  top: 0;
  /* position: fixed; */
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can user scroll the page ? I they can't maybe you can use fixed height for that. So, something like:

```
<script setup>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";

// Content
import ShowsSection from "./components/ShowsSection.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <Header class="header-top" />

    <!-- Content -->
    <ShowsSection />

    <!-- Use: fixed-bottom ?  -->
    <Footer class="footer-bottom" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.header-top {
  top: 0;
  /* position: fixed; */
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Now if the content still overlap with `header` or `footer`, you may want to use `flexbox` on the parent with `max-height` properties on each child, just to make sure they won't overlap.